# Why does Chrome wrap this table?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I may be missing the obvious, but any hint on why is Chrome wrapping the last column in this table? Shouldn't it calculate the column width so that the content fits? (given that the table does not actually fill the page). Both IE and Firefox seem to render it fine (or at least the way I expect it to be rendered).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.imgLink {
    margin: 0 8px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some more text</td>
        <td><span class="imgLink"><a href=""><img src="iconEdit.gif">Edit</a></span>
            <span class="imgLink"><a href=""><img src="iconDelete.gif">Delete</a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

The table is NOT filling the available page width.

Here's a screenshot showing the wrapping in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

I actually found a workaround for this -- just adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the last column of the table. Still, I believe that Chrome is not calculating the width properly, or perhaps I am missing something. I would like to know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here, but I believe that Chrome does make an error in calculating the width of the table cell. Since inline elements are not supposed to have margins, it calculates the width of the td without taking the margin into account. But then it draws the spans with the margins anyway, so the spans are to wide to fit in the td's calculated width, making them wrap.

So possible solutions are:

- make the spans `inline-block`, since inline blocks can have margins normally and then the calculations will be fine
- calculate what the eventual total width will be and give the td that width
- remove the margin from the span and giving it to the imgs
- don't use margins at all, but give the td some padding

Comment: A note on this: If I am interpreting the spec correctly, inline elements are actually allowed to have a margin. See section 10.3: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width, and also these test cases: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec10-03-01.htm. So while I believe that you are right in your interpretation of what Chrome is doing, I would say that the css is correct (i.e. I believe this is just a bug in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

Add display:inline-block to imgLink class: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/MFZX2/4/

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.imgLink {
    margin: 0 8px;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some more text</td>
        <td><span class="imgLink"><a href=""><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/a.png">Edit</a></span>
            <span class="imgLink"><a href=""><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/a.png">Delete</a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Another answer figured by Grodriguez is applying white-space: nowrap to last column.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I actually don't want the table to fill all the available width -- I only want it to be properly sized so that the contents fit without wrapping.

Comment: If there is no space it will wrap. There is no other way, you have to provide width to table or you have to change style of content in last column(decrease image or font sizes)

Comment: As described in my question, the table does NOT fill the available page width. There is plenty of space, yet it is wrapping. And this happens only in Chrome, not in FF or IE. Why?

Comment: This is what firefox shows up https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/fiddle.jpg

How can you say that its working in firefox 13, unless you post the entire code.

Comment: I *have* posted the entire code. For some reason you have not copied it into Jsfiddle. I have just done it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/MFZX2/. Now try that on FF and Chrome and you will see that Chrome is wrapping the last column while FF is not.

Comment: Actually chrome is rendering the broken image so its looking like that & ff is not. Just remove those image & check in chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/MFZX2/1/

Comment: "Just remove these images" is not a solution! The wrapping has nothing to do with the fact that the images are missing. The problem is perfectly reproducible with valid images as well (that's how I found it in the first place). I simply verified that it is also reproducible when the images are missing in order to post it on SO. Please take the time to understand the actual problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13213/discussion-between-svs-and-grodriguez)

Comment: Upvoting as this does work, just like white-space: nowrap. However I'd still like to know if this is a bug in Chrome or what. If someone has any extra info that'd be appreciated.

Comment: @Grodriguez As discussed in chat the reason i gave for this behaviour is described by Chris

Comment: I don't think that the argument described by Chris really applies.

Answer (score 1):

To add to SVS's answer the reason for this I suspect is that `span` is an inline element and as such is not allowed to have a margin. I would imagine that chrome is saying "well, if you want a margin on this you must want it to be a block element" and thus making it a block element. And being a block element now it won't sit the two `span`s side by side and so does a line break.

This is pretty much confirmed by the fact that setting the `display` to `inline-block` works as does removing the `margin` property from the styles.

Comment: The margin would be silently ignored anyway, so I don't think that answers the question of why this is happening.

Comment: Chris, thank you, but as @MrLister says I don't really think this explains the problem. Chrome is not handling these spans as block elements as you suggest -- look at the screenshot and you will see that it is wrapping in the middle of the second span, not between the two spans.

Comment: @MrLister: the fact that removing the margin fixes the issues suggests that it is not being silently ignored though as Grodriguez says I have got confused and it is not treating them as block as such...

Comment: @Chris Yes, sorry, my computer was in the process of crashing as I wrote that, so I couldn't test, but I see it now and it is definitely very strange behaviour, which I suspect is not what's supposed to happen. Doing some more testing now; not sure whether to call it a bug in Chrome yet.